# Properties.Settings variables not saving before form close

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Scenario:

I am using Properties.Settings to save the variable with a button click.  When I press the button, it will save the text inside of the textbox to Properties.Settings.Default.aString:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.aString = textBox1.Text;
    }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        label1.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.aString;
    }
```

Problem:

When the form loads for second time (after closing out of it and loading it again), the Properties.Settings variable didn't change to what I had in the textbox.  It might be a simple fix, but why didn't it remember the new value?  Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Answer (score 1):

The settings does not get saved automatically.

You have to call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save()`

> **MSDN** You must also explicitly call the Save method of this wrapper class in order to persist the user settings. You usually do this in the Closing event handler of the main form.

#### Sample

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - Application Settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx)